# codeigniter dynamic menu creation

Tags: codeigniter, dynamic, menu

hi I am trying to create a dynamic menu with submenus. I am almost done but the loop is repeating as you can see in the output image, which should  not happen. Error is like [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IODZq.jpg).Fruits main menu is repeating .[2].fruits sub category are splitting  and displaying .

[error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IODZq.jpg)

menu.php

```
$where_array = array('role_id' => $currentRolename , 'active_status' => '1');  //step1
        $table = 'bg_assignment';
        $query = $this->db->where($where_array)->get($table);
        foreach ($query->result() as $perm)
        { 

                $bg = $perm->bg_id;  
                $temp = '1';
                    $where_array2 = array('role_id' => $currentRolename ,  'permission' => '1');            //step2         
                    $table2 = 'role_permission';
                    $query2 = $this->db->where($where_array2)->get($table2);
                            foreach ($query2->result() as $r2)
                    {  
                     $bg_id = $r2->bg_id;

                        $where_array3 = array('bg_id' => $bg_id);                       
                        $table3 = 'bg_forms';

                        $query3 = $this->db->where($where_array3)->get($table3);
                                foreach ($query3->result() as $r3)
                                {

                        $where_array4 = array('phpfile_name' => $r3->phpfile_name);                     
                    $table4 = 'bg_forms';
                    $query4 = $this->db->where($where_array4)->get($table4);
                    foreach ($query4->result() as $r4)
                    {  
                            ?>


                            <li class="treeview <?php echo menu_li_active($r4->category_name); ?>">
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i>
                            <span>  <?php echo ($r4->category_name); ?></span>
                                <i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>
                            </a>    

                                    <ul class="treeview-menu">     
                                        <?php  echo menu_link($r4->controller.'/'.$r4->phpfile_name,    $r4->displayform_name); ?>                                  
                                      </ul>
                    <?php } }?> 
                        </li>
                    </li>

        <?php                                 
        }   
        }  
        ?>
```

Comment: Can you show us your db table structure including the content ?

Comment: please check the updated image

Comment: what exactly is bg_id 5 ?

Comment: bg_id comes from a table where id=5 and name is Fruits

Comment: show me that too pls

Comment: why not just use left join?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't do any test, just throw some ideas here, I think it will be much easier and clearer if you just use inner join in the query. Below code might have a syntax error, I don't have a similar environment as yours to do the tests.

```
<?php
//Let me just use open query to make this clear. 
$sql_query = '
select rp.bg_id,
       bf.category_name,
       bf.controller,
       bf.phpfile_name,
       bf.displayform_name   
from bg_assignment ba
inner join Role_permission rp
on ba.role_id = rp.role_id
and ba.bg_id = rp.bg_id --You might also want this line
inner join Bg_forms bf
on bg_id = bf.bg_id
where rp.permission = 1
and ba.active_status = 1
order by rp.bg_id, bf.displayform_name
';//I missed this semicolon

//Above sql query will give you two records
//Please test above query in your mysql to see if you can get below two records
/*
bg_id  category_name  controller  phpfile_name     displayform_name
5         Fruits         Product     index            Apple
5         Frutis         Product     sales            Orange
*/

$query = $this->db->query($sql_query);
$result = $query->result_array();

if(count($result) > 0){ // We get records!
  $html = '';
  for($i = 0; $i<count($result); $i++){
        $s = $result[$i];
        //Make the first li no matter what
        if($i === 0){
            $html.= '<li class="treeview">'.menu_li_active($s->category_name);
            $html.= '<a href="#">';
            $html.= '<i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i>';
            $html.= '<span>'.$s->category_name.'</span>';
            $html.= '<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>';
            $html.= '</a>';
            $html.= '</li>';
            $html.= '<ul class="treeview-menu">';
            $html.= menu_link($s->controller.'/'.$s->phpfile_name, $s->displayform_name);
            if(count($result)===1){
                $html.= '</ul>';
            }
        }
        else{
            if($s->category_name === $result[$i-1]->category_name){
                //If current category is the same as previous one, we put them in one tab
              $html.= menu_link($s->controller.'/'.$s->phpfile_name, $s->displayform_name); 
            }
            else{
                //If different, create a new tab
              $html.='</ul>';
              $html.= '<li class="treeview">'.menu_li_active($s->category_name);
              $html.= '<a href="#">';
              $html.= '<i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i>';
              $html.= '<span>'.$s->category_name.'</span>';
              $html.= '<i class="fa fa-angle-left pull-right"></i>';
              $html.= '</a>';
              $html.= '</li>';
              $html.= '<ul class="treeview-menu">';
              $html.= menu_link($s->controller.'/'.$s->phpfile_name, $s->displayform_name);
            }           
        }
    }
  $html.='</li>';
  echo $html;
}
?>
```

Comment: i am getting an error which says Severity: Parsing Error

Message: syntax error, unexpected '$query' (T_VARIABLE).at line $query = $this->db->query($sql_query);

Comment: Yes, I missed the semicolon

Comment: still getting error like----->Error Number: 1052

Column 'bg_id' in on clause is ambiguous

select rp.bg_id, bf.category_name, bf.controller, bf.phpfile_name, bf.displayform_name from bg_assignment ba inner join role_permission rp on ba.role_id = rp.role_id inner join bg_forms bf on bg_id = bf.bg_id where rp.permission = 1 and ba.active_status = 1 order by rp.bg_id, bf.displayform_name ....This error is getting in mysql query execution also

Comment: after rectifying error of ambiguous i am able to run sql code  but this code gives an output like 5 times fruits 5 times vegetables  etc

Comment: Yep, I don't have the whole picture of your database structure, I only can provide some ideas based on assumptions. Did you try to run the sql query on mysql directly? Can you confirm you get 2 records from the sql query?

Comment: this is what i am getting in sql 

bg_id  category_name    controller      phpfile_name     displayform_name
5         Fruits                     Product     index                                Apple
5         Frutis                     Product     sales                                Orange
5         veg                        Pro            abc                                   Onion
5         Spices                     abc          abc                                      abc

Comment: Ok, I see you added two more category_name which are 'veg' and 'Spices', I think above code should work.

Comment: the thing is that in role_permission bg_id=5 is given permission as 1 that means in bg_forms bg_id=5 products only to be displayed but it is displaying all products

Comment: the flow is like first bg_assignment table for role_id=12, bg_id has id 5 and active status as 1 that means Fruit should display.2nd role_permission table role_id=12 has given form permission by bgform_id=5 as permission as 1 that means when it comes to bg_forms table only bg_id =5 will display i.e., apple and orange and not others

Comment: Show me your bg-forms

Comment: the last image itself is for bg_forms  where i have total two bg_id as 5 and 5 for apple and orange(for fruits) you can add more as bg_id as 4 and 4 for veg1 and veg2(veg)

Comment: In the table Role_permission, if the permission is 0 where bg_id is 4, then you shouldn't see any veg records

Comment: Did you try to use the updated query in the answer? I added 'and ba.bg_id = rp.bg_id' in the sql query, this should limit the record to be fruits.

Comment: ya it is displaying other sub-menus also with bg_id also role_permission as 5 for all i dont no how it is 5 for all

Comment: You can try to add 'and bf.bg_id = 5' in the where clause, to see if you can get desired results.

Comment: error image updated what i am getting there bg_id_rp is nothing but bg_id of role_permission table i renamed it